# Exit popup + setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to create something like Exit Popup but limited to users residing on my page less than 10 seconds. I thought to use setInterval:

```
var counter = 0;

var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    // count
    console.log(counter);

    // Clear if more than 10 seconds
    if ( 10 < counter ) {
        console.log('Stop setInterval');
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }

    ++counter;
}, 1000);

if ( 10 > counter ) {
    // Simplified exit popup function
    $(window).mouseleave(function() {
        console.log('Popup');
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    });

}
```

First part of code works, but the second part executes even if counter is greater than 10. Why this is not working as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a counter. Just `bind` the event at page load, and `unbind` it after X seconds using a `setTimeout`:

```
$(window).bind('mouseleave', exitPopup);

setTimeout(function(){
    $(window).unbind('mouseleave', exitPopup);
},10000);

function exitPopup(){
    alert('Exit popup');
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo (3 seconds)


For this demo, make sure to put your cursor in the lower right window right at the beginning, and wait 3 seconds. It should not appear after that. If you don't wait, it'll show the popup.